# Handling phone shut down event in iOS

Tags: ios

I was wondering if I can be able to detect when the user turns off the phone. Is it possible? Does apple allow it? If they do, how? Thanks.

Comment: why do u need to know it?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Is it necessary to know it? Maybe he'd like some kind of logging?

Comment: yes to offer other ways to satisfy his needs.

Comment: Any update on that in 2021?

Answer (score 1):

As shutting down the device is an external event and has nothing to do with your app, you won't be able to find out if the user is trying to turn it off. The only thing you can actually find out is when your application is going to enter the background, what does not necessarily mean that the user turns the device off.

Checkout [UIApplication Delegate Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Comment: That's not completely true. There are messages sent in background to your application e.g. if you disable notifications for an app. So there *may* be an API for this, but if so, it's private.

Comment: I was referring to official ways :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are only few notifications allowed from the `UIDevice`, you can find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html).

There are some undocumented private frameworks, which could provide you such information, but if you use them, your app will be rejected.