# Detect before the iPhone shuts down?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

it it possible to detect before the iPhone shuts down to call actions like saving data to persistent store etc. for Swift

I tried the `appWillEnterBackground` and `appWillTerminate` function, but it didn´t work when i shut down the phone in app

Comment: You dont need to worry about the phone shutting down specifically. just use the `appWillEnterBackground` and `appWillTerminate` delegate methods in the AppDelegate

Comment: no, i tried it but it didn´t save when i turn off my phone in the app itself

Comment: Then I don't think there is anything else you can do, maybe someone has a solution but I haven't seen this before

Comment: okay thanks anyways

Comment: It doesn't look possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540103/handling-phone-shut-down-event-in-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling phone shut down event in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540103/handling-phone-shut-down-event-in-ios)

Comment: @SwiftNewling did you find a way to know that the phone is about to shut down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had to test it.

`applicationWillResignActive` will be called once you hold power for shut down and you have option to swipe.

If you swipe to shutdown `applicationDidEnterBackground` will be called then `applicationWillTerminate`.

Maybe try not to use breakpoint but print to test.

But not sure how to know if it is regular closing of the app or shutdown.

Comment: Dont need to know whether the phone is shutting down or not really. just need to know whats happening with your app. Good test, I didn't have time to do it

Comment: My guess is that he tried to use breakpoint, and it could not active breakpoint due to phone shutting donw.

Comment: it works, but only when shutting down with the menu. What is if the phone suddely shuts down it doesn´t work

Comment: Have you tried to suddenly shut it down. I think that then system can not notify the apps and that is it.

Comment: i tried the restart option in Hardware in simulator

Answer (score 0):

**There is no direct API in Swift to detect when an iPhone will shut down**, as Apple doesn't expose this information to third-party apps for security and privacy reasons.

AppDelegate methods like `applicationWillTerminate()` will also be called when you manually kill the app.

However, a hacky way would be to monitor the iPhone's battery level. There is an API for that, you can even use `NotificationCenter` to be notified on each battery level change.
Then, if `applicationWillTerminate()` is called and battery is empty, the phone is definitely shutting down.
**But, please not that battery drain is probably the most common way of shutting iPhone, but not the only one**, since user can always shut down or restart the iPhone manually.

If anyone is interested in monitoring battery status, [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27475577/13839521).